# Cannot impersonate to network drive using VS 2015 and IISExpress out of office

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

Working out of office using VPN to our domain with a C# web application, ASP.NET and .NET 4.5 (not MVC).  My laptop is not in the domain. I have an "impersonate" statement in the web.config which all works perfectly in the office (PC there is in domain). When running on the laptop, and the code comes to connect to the UNC drive over VPN, I get "username or password is incorrect".

I've tried setting the "processModel" entry in the IISExpress applicationhost.config file to the same credentials as the impersonate statement but this makes no difference.  I understood from searches that this should make the IISExpress application pool run under those credentials.

It is tricky putting the laptop in the domain for other reasons (internet not always available) and I'm not even sure this is the problem.  I've also used "cmdkey" to store the network credentials locally.

Any advice would be much appreciated - I've researched this for many hours and also modified "windowsAuthentication" and "anonymousAuthentication" in the applicationhost.config file from "deny" to "Allow", and set their corresponding "modules" to true from false.   Nothing makes any difference, nor does running IISExpress with admin rights.  Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question, but I often have to do remote support, and I also test the impact of upgrading 3rd party components before updating the office PC, so I need to solve this if possible.